# XPath in DOMDocument on WSDL file

Tags: php, xpath, wsdl, domdocument

I have some problems with make query to the XPath. I try to load WSDL file and them get some nodes using XPath.

```
$DOMDocument = new DOMDocument();
$DOMDocument->loadXML($wsdl);
$DOMXpath = new DOMXPath($DOMDocument);
$elements = $DOMXpath->query('//definitions//binding');
var_dump($elements);
```

Result is:

```
class DOMNodeList#15 (1) {
  public $length =>
  int(0)
}
```

Here is WSDL file: http://pastebin.com/YDRzbq3x

How to make correct XPath query to traversing over nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML has default namespace (`xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"`). In this case, you need to register a prefix that point to that default namespace URI, then use that prefix in your XPath query :

```
.......
$DOMXpath->registerNamespace('d', "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/");
$elements = $DOMXpath->query('//d:definitions//d:binding');
.......
```